# Update a record where a "newer" version exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a sql problem that I just cannot seem to solve.

Please imagine a table of software releases. In said table we have a release id, a product id, a version number and a status flag field.

*Please note I have heavily simplified this. In the real world this is a BIG table hence we introduced the status to avoid expensive grouping queries to only show the latest version of each product in the results etc.*

### Software Release

- ReleaseId (int)
- ProductId (int)
- Version (int)
- Status (int) // 0 = Old, 1 = current, 2 = future.

What we can do is create a select to find out which records are NOT the latest version so...

```
Select   * 
From     SoftwareRelease SR 
Where 
(
    Select   Count(*) 
    From     SoftwareRelease 
    Where    ProductId = SR.ProductId 
    And      Version > SR.Version
) > 0
```

But what we cannot do is a variant on this to update the status field appropriately. This is what we need to achieve for 0 (old) and 1(latest). Note it is assumed when the script is run that any records are old or latest. "2" or future records are for staging only and should not be considered.

Comment: Do WHERE EXISTS instead, and you'll save some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using window functions?

```
with toupdate as (
      select sr.*, row_number() over (partition by ProductId order by version desc) as seqnum
      from SoftwareRelease sr
     )
update toupdate
    set status = (case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    where seqnum = 1 and status = 0 or seqnum > 1 and status <> 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works really well. I am now analyzing how it works in order to learn from this experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `Row_Number()` function over the ProductId partition, and then updating the `Status` column based on whether it is the latest version or not:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By ProductId Order By Version Desc) Row_Number
    From    SoftwareRelease
    Where   Status <> 2
)
Update  Cte
Set     Status = Case When Row_Number = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End
```

Comment: thank you for this. I have accepted an alternative answer but this is equally as effective and deserves a thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with the table to self and check if the right side of the junction is `NULL` or not.

```
UPDATE SoftwareRelease SR
LEFT JOIN SoftwareRelease SR2 ON
  (SR.ProductId = SR2.ProductId And SR.Version > SR2.Version)
SET Status = Case When (SR2.ProductId is Null) Then 1 Else 0 End
```